# Port SecretKeySpec Java code converted to Python27

Tags: java, python-2.7

I have some java code I have been asked to convert to Python2.7 I have looked online and dont find a good example. 
The Java code is building a signature using SecretKeySpec function and HmacSHA256.

It takes a keyString as parameter and a message string a

Below is the function I need to convert to Python:

```
public static String genSig(String key, String Params) throws Exception {
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "HmacSHA256");
    Mac hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    hmacSha256.init(originalKey);
    hmacSha256.update(Params.getBytes());
    byte[] HmachSha256DigestBytes = hmacSha256.doFinal();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(HmachSha256DigestBytes);
}
```

I have looked into hmac and the hashlib libraries, but Im not sure what to use from these libraries to fulfill this conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```py
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

def generateSignatureFromParams(key, params):
    dig = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(key), msg=params, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    return base64.b64encode(dig).decode()

print generateSignatureFromParams("a2V5", "encrypt")
```

Notice to get HMACSha256, the `digestmod=hashlib.sha256` is important.